# Masonry working when initialized in HTML, not when initializing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, initialization, jquery-masonry

So I've had no problem getting Masonry to work when initializing in HTML, but since there is no way to implement the "imagesLoaded" without writing a little Javascript, I've decided to try and rework the site to initialize using jQuery.

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="masonry/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    $('#portfoliocontent').masonry
     ({
         columnWidth: 255,
         itemSelector: '.item1'
        ).imagesLoaded(function() {
            $('#portfoliocontent').masonry('reload');
          });
      });
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="portfoliocontent">
<div class="item1"><img src="images/masonthumb1.jpg"></div>
<div class="item1"><img src="images/masonthumb1.jpg"></div>
<div class="item1"><img src="images/masonthumb1.jpg"></div>
<div class="item1"><img src="images/masonthumb1.jpg"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The reason I'm reworking at all is because of the images stacking on load, and now I can't even get Masonry to initialize at all. I'm not the most familiar with Javascript or jQuery, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you loaded jquery ?

Comment: Just added this line in my head:

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Still no results.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Seems like I've debugged down to this error:


  "no such method 'reload' for masonry instance"

Comment: You have this vague ')' before .imagesLoaded. There is not '(' prior to it.

Comment: Once I remove this the error just moves down to line 31: "Unexpected token ; "

Comment: Which, once removed on line 31, proceeds to give me this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object .item1 has no method 'imagesLoaded' "

Comment: jQuery library is loading properly and as soon as I add 'class="js-masonry" '  to the portfoliocontent div, Masonry works properly, so I know its something in my jQuery code.

Comment: A JS Fiddle will really be helpful in your case. Could you create one?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MFq5N/3/

Comment: Sorry, relinked images updated on the JS Fiddle.

Comment: Newest JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MFq5N/14/

   No progress as far as making it work. Any help is apprecaited. My only current error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " on the first line of my Javascript. Any help is appreciated, thank you!